# Supremum of Stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation

Let $X(t)$ be a stochastic process. Let $A=E[\sup_{t \in T} X(t)]$ and $B= \sup_{t \in T} E[ X(t)]$. Can we establish any relation between A and B (Is there any? ) for e.g. $A>B \text{ or } A<B$. Prove the relation also.

Comment: For Brownian motion and many related processes, it is easy to see that $A>B $ (since the pathwise sup is always non negative and often positive, while the pointwise average is always zero). I think this will turn out to be general.

Comment: Let $M=\sup\limits_{t \in T} X(t)$ then, for every $t$, $M\geqslant X(t)$ almost surely hence $A=E(M)\geqslant E(X(t))$. This holds for every $t$ hence $A\geqslant\sup\limits_{t\in T}E(X(t))=B$, end of the proof. (The only case when $A=B$ is when $X(t)=M$ almost surely, for every $t$, that is, when $X(t)$ does not depend on $t$.)

Answer (score 3):

The functional $F[X]=\max_{t \in T} X(t)$ is convex. So by Jensen's inequality, $E[F[X]] \geq F[E[X]]$. We can have strict inequality: for instance we do when $X$ is Brownian motion.

Comment: I don't think it is right to assume max function defined here is convex. It would have been convex if X(t) were convex but It's not given anywhere.

Comment: @user3135030 Convexity of the maximum functional amounts to saying $\lambda \max_{t \in T} X(t) + (1-\lambda) \max_{t \in T} Y(t) \geq \max_{t \in T} \lambda X(t) + (1-\lambda) Y(t)$, for all real valued functions $X,Y$ defined on $T$ and all $\lambda \in [0,1]$. This definitely holds (you will expect equality when the maximum of $X$ and $Y$ are both attained at the same point; you will expect inequality otherwise). Try playing with the case when $T$ is just two points for intuition.